# Adding dropdown in table head bootstrap 3

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, html-table

I am trying to add dropdown in table head, but I got an error in html5 validation, what will be correct markup?

Here is example fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/52VtD/9883/

and HTML

```
 <table class="table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th class="dropdown">
                   <a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle">Messages <b class="caret"></b></a>
                   <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                      <li><a href="#">Inbox</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Drafts</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Sent Items</a></li>
                      <li class="divider"></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Trash</a></li>
                   </ul>
                </th>
                <th>First Name</th>
                <th>Last Name</th>
                <th>Email</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
</table>
```